Built-in laptop keyboard only functions when booting with noapic
I have an Eluktronics MECH-17 G2 laptop whose built-in keyboard (the Cherry MX mechanical option) is completely nonfunctional with any Linux distro I have tried. That list includes Ubuntu (18.04 and 24.04), Debian, Mint, Arch, Nobara, Fedora, and OpenSUSE Tumbleweed (which is what I currently have installed). All of those distros are consistent in that the keyboard works completely fine in GRUB (and Windows/BIOS), but is completely dead once booted. The touchpad works completely fine, as do USB keyboards. If I add the noapic kernel parameter, the keyboard works, but then my touchpad stops working, and the system can only see/use 1 of my 16 CPU cores, so that's obviously not a long term solution.
I checked /proc/interrupts and it looks like i8042 is consistently being registered at index 1 and put on CPU12, and I've noticed that if I press buttons on my keyboard and then check /proc/interrupts again, the number of interrupts goes up. So there's at least something happening. If I boot with noapic, everything is handled by CPU0 and the other 15 CPU cores don't show up in the output.
The other kernel parameters I've tried that haven't helped are:

i8042.dumbkbd=1
i8042.nopnp
i8042.nomux
i8042.reset
i8042.direct
nolapic - freezes immediately after GRUB
acpi=ht - also makes external monitors not work
pci=noacpi - freezes on a black screen while booting
acpi=off - keyboard kinda works, but lots of keypresses are missed and the whole system becomes pretty laggy
irqpoll & irqfixup - tried both separately & together, but my system freezes during boot either way

Here's the output of dmesg | grep -iE "acpi|apic|keyboard|i8042|serio" with the acpi.debug_layer=0xFFFFFFFF & acpi.debug_level=0xF parameters active:
[    0.342432] [      T1] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKA configured for IRQ 0
[    0.342532] [      T1] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKB configured for IRQ 0
[    0.342620] [      T1] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKC configured for IRQ 0
[    0.342729] [      T1] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKD configured for IRQ 0
[    0.342827] [      T1] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKE configured for IRQ 0
[    0.342911] [      T1] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKF configured for IRQ 0
[    0.342994] [      T1] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKG configured for IRQ 0
[    0.343078] [      T1] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKH configured for IRQ 0
[    0.343884] [      T1] ACPI Debug:  "BAT0_STA Start"
[    0.344547] [      T1] ACPI: BIOS _OSI("Processor Aggregator Device") is supported
[    0.351620] [      T1] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[    0.351621] [      T1] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[    0.351625] [      T1] ACPI: EC: EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.351627] [      T1] ACPI: EC: GPE=0x4
[    0.351628] [      T1] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.SBRG.EC0_: Boot DSDT EC initialization complete
[    0.351630] [      T1] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.SBRG.EC0_: EC: Used to handle transactions and events
[    0.355774] [      T1] ACPI Debug:  "BAT0_STA Start"
[    0.355807] [      T1] ACPI: BIOS _OSI("Processor Aggregator Device") is supported
[    0.357110] [      T1] ACPI: BIOS _OSI("Processor Aggregator Device") is supported
[    0.358791] [      T1] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.369049] [      T1] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.371626] [      T1] ACPI Debug:  "BAT0_STA Start"
[    0.372544] [      T1] ACPI: BIOS _OSI("Processor Aggregator Device") is supported
[    0.372829] [      T1] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 4 devices
[    0.378953] [      T1] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
[    0.393255] [      T1] AMD-Vi: Extended features (0x246577efa2254afa, 0x0): PPR NX GT [5] IA GA PC GA_vAPIC
[    0.393333] [      T1] AMD-Vi: Virtual APIC enabled
[    0.517571] [     T22] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P000: Found 3 idle states
[    0.517667] [     T65] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P001: Found 3 idle states
[    0.517796] [     T23] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P002: Found 3 idle states
[    0.517982] [     T71] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P003: Found 3 idle states
[    0.518159] [     T29] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P004: Found 3 idle states
[    0.518337] [     T77] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P005: Found 3 idle states
[    0.518503] [     T35] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P006: Found 3 idle states
[    0.518682] [     T83] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P007: Found 3 idle states
[    0.518868] [     T41] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P008: Found 3 idle states
[    0.519050] [     T89] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P009: Found 3 idle states
[    0.519233] [     T47] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P00A: Found 3 idle states
[    0.519423] [     T95] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P00B: Found 3 idle states
[    0.519607] [     T53] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P00C: Found 3 idle states
[    0.519785] [    T101] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P00D: Found 3 idle states
[    0.519958] [     T59] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P00E: Found 3 idle states
[    0.520127] [    T107] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P00F: Found 3 idle states
[    0.522836] [      T1] hpet_acpi_add: no address or irqs in _CRS
[    0.648770] [      T1] ACPI: bus type drm_connector registered
[    0.650878] [      T1] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.650880] [      T1] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
[    0.653205] [      T1] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.857519] [    T144] atkbd serio0: Failed to deactivate keyboard on isa0060/serio0
[    0.994972] [      T1] acpi PNP0C0F:01: hash matches
[    1.257008] [    T144] atkbd serio0: Failed to enable keyboard on isa0060/serio0
[    1.257121] [    T144] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
[    1.770541] [    T496] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRB]
[    1.770772] [    T115] ACPI Debug:  "BAT0_STA Start"
[    1.770785] [    T496] ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    1.771135] [    T496] ACPI: button: Lid Switch [LID1]
[    1.771779] [    T115] ACPI Debug:  "ECBE"
[    1.776647] [    T115] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 Start"
[    1.779283] [    T115] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 End"
[    1.780675] [    T115] ACPI: battery: Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    1.786030] [    T485] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    1.925611] [    T464] ACPI: video: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: no  rom: yes  post: no)
[    1.926210] [    T464] ACPI: video: Video Device [VGA] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    3.645576] [    T475] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 Start"
[    3.648268] [    T475] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 End"
[    3.907609] [    T500] hid-generic 0003:046D:C534.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:06:00.4-1.1/input0
[    4.034598] [    T500] input: Razer Razer DeathAdder Elite Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.3/0000:07:00.4/usb9/9-1/9-1.4/9-1.4:1.1/0003:1532:005C.000A/input/input22
[    4.095304] [    T500] hid-generic 0003:1532:005C.000A: input,hidraw9: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer DeathAdder Elite] on usb-0000:07:00.4-1.4/input1
[    4.250544] [    T500] hid-generic 0003:1532:005C.000B: input,hidraw10: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer DeathAdder Elite] on usb-0000:07:00.4-1.4/input2
[    4.494998] [    T473] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C534.0004: hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:06:00.4-1.1/input0
[    4.778406] [    T625] input: Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075 Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0006/0003:046D:4075.000C/input/input25
[    4.968034] [    T625] hid-generic 0003:046D:4075.000C: input,hidraw11: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075] on usb-0000:06:00.4-1.1/input1:1
[    5.199844] [    T502] input: Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0006/0003:046D:4075.000C/input/input31
[    5.327980] [    T502] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4075.000C: input,hidraw12: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4075] on usb-0000:06:00.4-1.1/input1:1
[    6.231531] [    T726] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 Start"
[    6.234819] [    T726] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 End"
[    6.256859] [    T800] acpi-tad ACPI000E:00: Missing _PRW
[    6.272482] [    T808] ACPI: AC: AC Adapter [AC0] (on-line)
[    6.275292] [    T790] ACPI: thermal: Thermal Zone [ECTZ] (74 C)
[    6.281168] [    T790] ACPI: thermal: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (20 C)
[    7.209251] [   T1236] ACPI Warning: \_SB.NPCF._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20240322/nsarguments-61)
[    7.209302] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "------- NVPCF DSM --------"
[    7.209329] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "   NVPCF sub-func#0"
[    7.209346] [   T1236] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.GPP0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20240322/nsarguments-61)
[    7.209475] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.209543] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NVOP >>>"
[    7.209634] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "------- NV GPS DSM --------"
[    7.209656] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "GPS fun 0"
[    7.209701] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "------- NV JT DSM --------"
[    7.209720] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "JT fun0 JT_FUNC_SUPPORT"
[    7.209791] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "------- NVPCF DSM --------"
[    7.209842] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "------- NV GPS DSM --------"
[    7.209869] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "GPS fun 19"
[    7.209924] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "------- NV JT DSM --------"
[    7.209949] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "JT fun1 JT_FUNC_CAPS"
[    7.210114] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NVOP >>>"
[    7.503087] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.503190] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.503298] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.503391] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.503465] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.503557] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.503631] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.503729] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.503803] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.503895] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.503967] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.504058] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.504130] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.504222] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.504294] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.504385] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.504458] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.504549] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.504621] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.504713] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.504785] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.504876] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.504948] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.505040] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.505112] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.505203] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.505276] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.505367] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.505439] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.505531] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.505603] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.505695] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.505768] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.505860] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get DR key"
[    7.528526] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NVOP >>>"
[    7.803919] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    7.806673] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "------- NV GPS DSM --------"
[    7.806706] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "GPS fun 32"
[    7.806765] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "------- NV GPS DSM --------"
[    7.806801] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "GPS fun 42"
[    8.176526] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "------- NV GPS DSM --------"
[    8.176564] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "GPS fun 42"
[    8.267855] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "------- NV GPS DSM --------"
[    8.267884] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "GPS fun 19"
[    8.373195] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    8.373298] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get VK key"
[    8.373407] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    8.373500] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get VK key"
[    8.373571] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    8.373671] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get VK key"
[    8.373744] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    8.373835] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "Get VK key"
[    8.373957] [   T1236] ACPI Debug:  "<<< NBCI >>>"
[    9.523356] [   T1652] ACPI Debug:  "------- NV GPS DSM --------"
[    9.523386] [   T1652] ACPI Debug:  "GPS fun 19"
[   13.388784] [   T1870] ACPI Debug:  "------- NV GPS DSM --------"
[   13.388854] [   T1870] ACPI Debug:  "GPS fun 19"
[   15.420044] [   T1372] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 Start"
[   15.424616] [   T1372] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 End"
[   20.951320] [   T2107] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 Start"
[   20.954464] [   T2107] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 End"
[   22.647589] [    T120] Modules linked in: rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq af_packet nft_fib_inet nft_fib_ipv4 nft_fib_ipv6 nft_fib nft_reject_inet nf_reject_ipv4 nf_reject_ipv6 nft_reject nft_ct nft_chain_nat ip6table_nat ip6table_mangle ip6table_raw ip6table_security iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_mangle iptable_raw iptable_security ip6table_filter ip6_tables qrtr cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nf_tables iptable_filter nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 vfat fat snd_acp6x_pdm_dma snd_soc_acp6x_mach snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_amd_acp63 nvidia_uvm(POE) snd_sof_amd_vangogh snd_sof_amd_rembrandt snd_sof_amd_renoir snd_sof_amd_acp snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof iwlmvm snd_sof_utils snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_pci_ps snd_amd_sdw_acpi soundwire_amd snd_hda_codec_generic soundwire_generic_allocation snd_hda_scodec_component soundwire_bus snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211 intel_rapl_msr amd_atl snd_soc_core intel_rapl_common snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg
[   22.647684] [    T120]  snd_intel_sdw_acpi libarc4 snd_usb_audio edac_mce_amd snd_compress snd_hda_codec btusb snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_usbmidi_lib btrtl snd_rpl_pci_acp6x uvcvideo snd_ump snd_acp_pci snd_hda_core kvm_amd btintel snd_rawmidi snd_acp_legacy_common videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm uvc snd_seq_device snd_pci_acp6x snd_hwdep spd5118 asus_wmi btmtk videobuf2_memops nvidia(POE) iwlwifi platform_profile snd_pci_acp5x r8169 snd_pcm videobuf2_v4l2 kvm i2c_piix4 snd_rn_pci_acp3x snd_timer realtek snd_acp_config sparse_keymap pcspkr wmi_bmof i2c_smbus videobuf2_common k10temp bluetooth snd_soc_acpi mdio_devres snd_pci_acp3x snd cfg80211 soundcore libphy rfkill thermal ac amd_pmc joydev acpi_tad tiny_power_button nvme_fabrics fuse nvme_keyring loop dm_mod efi_pstore configfs nfnetlink dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid amdgpu crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel sha512_ssse3 sha256_ssse3 sha1_ssse3 amdxcp i2c_algo_bit drm_ttm_helper ttm drm_exec gpu_sched
[   22.647800] [    T120]  drm_suballoc_helper drm_buddy xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas nvme drm_display_helper hid_multitouch ucsi_acpi xhci_hcd nvme_core aesni_intel cec typec_ucsi video hid_generic gf128mul crypto_simd cryptd usbcore roles ccp rc_core sp5100_tco typec nvme_auth battery button wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid serio_raw btrfs blake2b_generic libcrc32c crc32c_intel xor raid6_pq v4l2loopback(O) videodev mc msr i2c_dev efivarfs
[   24.267703] [   T2619] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 Start"
[   24.270202] [   T2619] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 End"
[   34.849014] [    T182] ACPI Debug:  "=== QD1 ==="
[   34.857856] [    T182] ACPI Debug:  "------- NV GPS DSM --------"
[   34.857899] [    T182] ACPI Debug:  "GPS fun 19"
[   45.851692] [   T1992] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 Start"
[   45.856599] [   T1992] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 End"
[   75.874971] [   T1992] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 Start"
[   75.878080] [   T1992] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 End"
[  105.908652] [   T1992] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 Start"
[  105.912606] [   T1992] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 End"
[  135.943567] [   T1992] ACPI Debug:  "BST1 Start"

Btw the manufacturer officially does not support Linux, so I'm not getting any help from them.
Thanks a lot to anyone who takes the time to reply, have a good one.

I was able to get it working! Somebody on Reddit pointed me at this forum thread that I'd missed: https://forums.opensuse.org/t/keyboard-not-working-on-laptop-amd-asus-tuf/165741/14 where somebody had a very similar issue, but with a different laptop model (an Asus TUF Gaming A15 FA507NU). Essentially, the fix was to recompile my kernel from source, after editing drivers/acpi/resource.c to add the following entry:
    {
        .matches = {
            DMI_MATCH(DMI_SYS_VENDOR, "Eluktronics, Inc."),
            DMI_MATCH(DMI_BOARD_NAME, "MECH-17"),
        },
    },

After building/installing the kernel w/ that small edit and booting into it, the keyboard is working great! I had to reinstall the NVIDIA drivers (had to do it with their .run file, reinstalling them via zypper didn't work for some reason), but now my system seems to be finally in a pretty-much-fully-working state.
I still don't fully understand what this fix is doing, but it seems like there's a hardcoded list of hardware that requires some sort of override in the acpi driver in order for the keyboard to work, and my laptop model just needed to be added to that list.
